# How can I turn every image with a specific class into a hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I'm designing courses inside a learning management system and I'm looking to make all the images in a specific class clickable, so clicking the photo opens a full resolution version of the image.

Right now, it looks like this:

```
<img class="question-image" alt="" src="https://d16smq18f8amlc.cloudfront.net/26154/assessment/879087_1.jpg">
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
<a href="https://contentlive.s3.amazonaws.com/26154/page/f0b69777.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://contentlive.s3.amazonaws.com/26154/page/f0b69777" style="height: 333px; width: 500px;">
</a>
```

Basically, I want to turn images into hyperlinks to the images' full resolution versions. Is this possible?

Comment: show us some fiddle, it would be easier to help you

Comment: The easiest thing you can do is doing something like: <a class="question-image" alt="" src="mySrc" target="_blank" style="myStyle"></a> in order get a 'clickable image'. You can also wrap your imageClass into a <a>.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>on demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <img class="question-image" alt="" src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/logo-socareers.svg?v=16f4bcd961f9" />

    <script>        
        $(".question-image").click(function () {
            window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Create function and pass parameter for respective URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this. **[The Fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lsj5chv/)**

```
<a href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1jEJsCAhAJDrzQoU9Cp6OA9xQQ2hdivqHa6kbtu_fzvXhE15A" target="_blank" >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1jEJsCAhAJDrzQoU9Cp6OA9xQQ2hdivqHa6kbtu_fzvXhE15A" alt="" style="height: 333px; width: 500px;"> 
</a>
```